# Optimizing Camel HTTP4 with KeepAlive

Tags: tomcat, https, apache-camel, keep-alive, camel-http

I want to be able to POST messages to an HTTPS server using Camel at a pretty fast rate ( > 1500/sec) using only one connection to the server.

I tried setting keepAlive to true, but I still cant see any improvement in speed.

Took the tcpdump while sending 5 messages, and I find 5 SYN/ACK packets on wireshark.
Possibly the SSL certificate is also being sent on each POST. (102 packets captured by the tcpdump, but all I am sending are 5 "HelloWorld" strings)

Is there any way I can speed things up? This is the code I used:

```
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    final HttpComponent http = (HttpComponent) context.getComponent("https4");

    http.setConnectionsPerRoute(1);
    http.setMaxTotalConnections(1);
    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    http.setHttpConfiguration(httpConfiguration);;

    context.addComponent("fcpHttpComponent", http);
    template = context.createProducerTemplate();

    headers.put(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.POST);
    final String endpoint = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443"; 

    try {
        httpEndpoint = new HttpEndpoint(endpoint, http, new URI(endpoint));
        httpEndpoint.configureProperties(headers);
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
                .setSoKeepAlive(true)
                .setSoReuseAddress(true)
                .setTcpNoDelay(true)
                .setSndBufSize(10)
                .build();
        clientConnectionManager.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);

        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        clientBuilder.setMaxConnPerRoute(1);
        clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(clientConnectionManager);
        clientBuilder.build();
        ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy();
        clientBuilder.setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy );
        httpEndpoint.setClientBuilder(clientBuilder);

        httpEndpoint.setClientConnectionManager(clientConnectionManager);

        template.start();
        context.start();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception while starting Camel context ", e);
    }

    //Call this method 5 times 
    template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders(httpEndpoint, message, headers);
```

The SSL certificate details are given as JVM arguments. I am able to POST data but the speed is something I need to improve.

[Update] I am using Apache Tomcat 8 as my server. 
Set the following in server.xml:

```
 <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/x/store.jks" keystorePass="y"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" keepAliveTimeout="-1" />
```

Is there something else I need to configure on my server as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the netty4Http component.
Here is some sample code:

```
private DataWriter() {
this.context = new DefaultCamelContext();
try {
    final NettyHttpComponent nettyHttpComponent = this.context.getComponent("netty4-http",
            org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpComponent.class);
    this.context.addComponent("nettyhttpComponent", nettyHttpComponent);
    this.template = this.context.createProducerTemplate();
    this.headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.headers.put("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
    String trustCertificate = "&ssl=true&passphrase=" + "123456" + "&keyStoreFile="
            + "C:/Users/jpisaac/certs/publicKey.store"
            + "&trustStoreFile=C:/Users/jpisaac/certs/publicKey.store" ;

    this.endpoint = "netty4-http:"+ "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/server"
            + "?useByteBuf=true&disableStreamCache=true&connectTimeout=30000&requestTimeout=30000&reuseChannel=true"
            + "&keepAlive=true&tcpNoDelay=true&sync=false&reuseAddress=true&sendBufferSize=1000"
            + trustCertificate;
    this.template.start();
    this.context.start();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Exception while starting Camel context ", e);
}
}

 public void sendData(final String message) {
try {
    CompletableFuture<Object> future=this.template.asyncRequestBodyAndHeaders(this.endpoint, message, this.headers);
    System.err.println("Sent data "+message);
} catch (final CamelExecutionException e) {
    LOG.error("Error while sending data", e);
}
}
```